# Can i use, within the same function: "response.render" and "response.writeHead" options?

Tags: node.js, cookies, pug

```
response.render('welcome-page.jade', {
    title : 'Welcome user!',
    remoteUser : request.remoteUser,
    id : "identification"
});

// To Write a Cookie
response.writeHead(200, {
  'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=test',
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
});
```

Is it possible to send also cookies at the client using "response.render", if not how can i resolve this problem?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`res.set`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.set) to set response headers, and [`res.cookie`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie) to set cookies.

And as @TheHippo pointed out, you probably have to do this before you invoke `render`.

Comment: Also I believe you should set Headers (and of course Cookies) before you send the "actual" response.

Comment: Yes, you probably have to do that.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I've used the method: "response.setHeader(name, value)"